# jQuery using $.ajax to post multipart form data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to post a multi/part form data (which includes some data + images) to my client server API. Even using `$.ajax` returns success response, nothing is being posted. Can someone please check my code and let me know what exactly I am doing wrong and how to fix it? *Note: I've tried using FormData but still the same result. Also I've tried same exact code on local server as shown below and I get the same result*

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/project/api/client.php',
    data: {
        action: 'editclientprofile',
        image: clientPicture,
        name: clientName,
        email: clientEmail,
        address: clientAddress
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success...');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error...');                    
    }
});
```

Comment: I miss a ' in console.log('error...);

Comment: you have missed a ' in `console.log('error...)`;

Comment: Thanks guys but that's not what stopping Ajax from posting my data :)